# emacs remember tag template returning as invalid

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have been following [Charles Cave's GTD](http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/remember.html#sec-4) description for using emacs' remember mode for making todo lists, etc.  I understand the tutorial is a bit dated, so any suggestions on how to update the [.emacs file](http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/mydotemacs.txt) to org-capture will be appreciated.  That being said, that is not the current problem.

I define the org templates like so:

```
(setq org-remember-templates
    '(("Todo" ?t "\n* TODO %^{Brief Description} %^g%? \nAdded: %U" "~/orgfiles/GTD/newgtd.org" "Tasks")
      ("Journal"   ?j "** %^{Head Line} %U %^g\n%i%?"  "~/orgfiles/GTD/journal.org")
      ("Clipboard" ?c "** %^{Head Line} %U %^g\n%c\n%?"  "~/orgfiles/GTD/journal.org")
      ("Receipt"   ?r "** %^{BriefDesc} %U %^g\n%?"   "~/orgfiles/GTD/finances.org")
      ("Book" ?b "** %^{Book Title} %t :BOOK: \n%[~/orgfiles/GTD/.book_template.txt]\n" 
         "~/orgfiles/GTD/journal.org")
      ("Film" ?f "** %^{Film Title} %t :FILM: \n%[~/orgfiles/GTD/.film_template.txt]\n" 
         "~/orgfiles/GTD/journal.org")
      ("Daily Review" ?a "** %t :COACH: \n%[~/orgfiles/GTD/.daily_review.txt]\n" 
         "~/orgfiles/GTD/journal.org")
      ("Private" ?p "\n* %^{topic} %T \n%i%?\n" "~/orgfiles/GTD/privnotes.org")
      ("Contact" ?c "\n* %^{Name} :CONTACT:\n%[~/orgfiles/contemp.txt]\n" 
               "~/orgfiles/GTD/privnotes.org")
      ("Someday"   ?s "** %^{Someday Heading} %U\n%?\n"  "~/orgfiles/GTD/someday.org")
      ("Vocab"   ?v "** %^{Word?}\n%?\n"  "~/orgfiles/GTD/vocab.org")
     )
   )
```

This is pretty much cut-and-paste from the tutorial.  When I attempt a "Todo" (C-c r t shortcut) a new emacs window opens in remember mode with text

```
* TODO %^g%?
```

already within the screen.  There is something going on here because I should only have

```
* TODO
```

showing up, with remember waiting for me to make an entry.  However, if I remove the %g from the template definition all works well (I just can't insert a tag while creating my entry).  I have searched around to see if perhaps the %^g entry has been changed (maybe when remember was replaced by capture), but I have found nothing so far.  Is there anything wrong with the template as defined?  Any help (especially to references for further reading) will be appreciated.

Unfortunately my organization is stuck on RHEL 6, so updating emacs is not currently possible.

org-mode version: 8.3.4
emacs version: 23.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You have a recent enough version of org that you can ditch `org-remember` (which is obsolete and no longer maintained AFAIK) and start using `org-capture` instead. You can use the function `org-capture-import-remember-templates` to translate your `org-remember-templates` to `org-capture-templates`.

If you still have troubles after that, post to the mailing list.